# Let users download and set induvidual blog themes Drupal 7

Tags: 7, users, theming

I want to enable users customize their own blog appearance and theme the same way it is being done in multi-user blogging sites such as [wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com), [tumblr.com](http://tumblr.com), [typepad.com](http://typepad.com), etc.

1. Users can set a theme to their blog
2. Users can manage some settings regarding ther blog appearance (background color, fonts, etc.)
3. Users can download themes or even make their own themes available for others.
4. The theme setting only affects the user blog page (but not the general site layout).

Any possible suggestions to make part of those requirements implemented quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Letting them download and put up whatever theme that they want sounds like it might be a major security issue for your site, since they could put whatever PHP that they want into the theme files and it would run. I'd suggest making a specific set of themes you have picked available and letting users choose from those. There are modules like Theme key to enable using different themes: http://drupal.org/project/themekey

Comment: That was very helpful... theme key is a nice solid solution and very easy for implementing. After a very long search I did not find any ready made solution for letting users downloading their own theme or altering their own blog appearance - this is probably the most you can get without having to create your own module :-)